# Calculate the radius of a circle given the chord length and height of a segment.

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

Please, could some one explain how the first equation becomes the second equation.

1. $a^2 + (r-h)^2=(r\sin{\theta})^2+(r\cos\theta)^2=r^2$
2. The solution to this is expressed as:
   $r=\frac{a^2+h^2}{2h}$

Many thanks,
Martin

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... I'm *guessing* that the first equation (ignoring the intervening trig) should be $$a^2+(r-h)^2=r^2$$ (note the "$+$"), and also, that the second equation is supposed to be $$r=(a^2+h^2)/(2h) \qquad\text{that is,}\qquad r = \frac{a^2+h^2}{2h}$$ Given those fixes, can you get from one to the other?

Comment: Thank you for the fixes, I will try to formulate my requests better next time. It is the step between one equation to obtain the “ r “ expression.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
   a^2 + (r-h)^2 = (r \ sin\theta)^2 + (r \ cos\theta)^2 \\
   \iff a^2 + r^2 - 2rh + h^2 = r^2(sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta)
\end{gather*}
From here, we can use the pythagorean identity: $sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta = 1$ (which is trivial to prove if you draw a unit circle) in order to rewrite the right hand side of the equation as just $r^2(1) = r^2$. Hence, we get:

\begin{gather*}
a^2 + r^2 - 2rh + h^2 = r^2 \\
\iff a^2 - 2rh + h^2 = 0 \\
\iff 2rh = a^2 + h^2 \\
\iff r = \frac{a^2 + h^2}{2h}
\end{gather*}

$Q.E.D.$

Answer (score 0):

Faster: Use the Geometric Mean Theorem („$h^2=pq$“) on the right triangle with half the segment as height and the circle diameter containing the segment height as hypothenusis. That is,
$$(a/2)^2=h\cdot(2r-h)$$
And solve for $r$.